# Slick 3.0 delete and returning values

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

If I want a returning value when inserting a new row, I can do something like

```
val insertQuery = myTable returning myTable.map(_.id) += SomeData(someString)
```

How can I achieve the same effect when deleting?

I tried

```
val deleteQuery = myTable filter (_.id ===id) returning myTable.map(_.someColumn) delete
```

But apparently this does not compile.

I can resort to the `for` comprehension but I wonder if there is a shorter way.

Comment: The returning value of deleting is the number of rows deleted. I guess if you want to return the values itself, you need to select them first before you delete them.

Answer (score 4):

The best way I know of to do this is to do something like:

```
val query = db.filter(....)
val action = for {
   results <- query.result
   _ <- query.delete
} yield results
db.run(action.withTransactionIsolation(TransactionIsolation.RepeatableRead))
```

Wish it was shorter.

Comment: As mentioned in the question. Using `for` comprehension obviously works. I was looking for an inline solution.